# How to call bpy.ops.view3d.cursor3d() from another operator?

Tags: python, 3d-view, add-on

I want to set the 3d cursor location using `bpy.ops.view3d.cursor3d()` operator before calling my own operator with a shortcut.
This is what I have tried-

```
class Add_obj(Operator):
    bl_idname = 'ob.add_object'
    bl_label = 'Add object'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO' }

    def execute(context,self):
        bpy.ops.view3d.cursor3d()  #place 3d cursor on mouse click just like pressing SHIFT+RIGHT click
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()  #add object
        return {'FINISHED'}

addon_keymaps = []


def register():
    register_class(Add_obj)
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
# Adding a Shortcut for the operator
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = kc.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("ob.add_object", type= 'RIGHTMOUSE', value='PRESS',
        shift=True,alt=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km,kmi))

def unregister():
    for km,kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()
    unregister_class(Add_obj)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

But when I press the shortcut `SHIFT+ALT+RIGHT click` it gives this error and adds a cube-
`ERROR (wm.operator): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_290\blender.git\source\blender\windowmanager\intern\wm_event_system.c:1317 wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call 'VIEW3D_OT_cursor3d`

Comment: Possibly easier to make this a modal operator, capture some mouse event, set cursor,  and add the cube.  See the modal examples in _`Text Editor > Templates > Python > Modal Operator *`_  Consider in future adding imports etc to make a minimal working script.

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you! I managed to achieve what I wanted by following the raycast modal example from templates.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. Add an `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` to the 3d cursor operator:

```py
    def execute(context,self):
        bpy.ops.view3d.cursor3d('INVOKE_DEFAULT') # put it at the start, before any arguments
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        return {'FINISHED'}
```